# How to do a lookup that returns more than the first instance of a match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I am working on hiring new teaching assistants for summer. We have our main database for the TAs for summer semester called "input". We have a database of previous TAs in a tab called "the pit." I am using an xlookup formula to see if a TA's summer course matches their old course listed in the pit. The TA will go to a different sheet based on if they have the same course as last time or not. The problem I have is that for TAs with more than one previous job, the xlookup only looks to see if the top-most row with that TA's name has a course that matches, when I need it to check all of them so that TAs are not being identified as having a brand new course that they haven't taught before, even if the current course is also listed farther down in "the pit". Here is my formula:

```
=IF(XLOOKUP($B5,'The Pit'!$L:$L,'The Pit'!O:O,"Enter here")<>R5,"Job Change/Raises","Same Job")
```

Where B5 is the TA ID, the Pit L:L is TA ID as well, the Pit O:O is course, and R5 is the current summer course.

Is there a way to tell it to look at all instances of the student ID for a match? Or give me a drop down choice of which row I'd like to use? I would prefer to keep using xlookup, but open to other formulas or ideas.

Comment: Since you're using XLOOKUP look into `FILTER`

Comment: Untested: `=IF(FILTER('The Pit'!$O:$O,'The Pit'!$L:$L=$B5)<>R5,"Job Change/Raises","Same Job")`